# Paginate results, offset and limit

Tags: python, sql

If I am developing a web service for retrieving some album names of certain artist using an [API](https://musicbrainz.org/doc/Development/XML_Web_Service/Version_2), and I am asked:

> The service should give the possibility to paginate results. It should support 'ofset=' and 'limit='.
>   The default limit is 50 and you can increase that up to 150.

How should I interpret that? I get confused with the meaning of "ofset" and "limit"

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/queries-limit.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paginating means you do not get *all* results, but pages with up to `limit` results.

```
limit  == how many results to return per call  
offset ==  which "page" you are on 

if limit == 50 and offset == 150 you return results 151 to 200 (page 4)
```

You should use a default `limit` of 50 results and return 150 results per page at maximum even if a `limit` of 1000 is requested.

Comment: Thanks for the good and fast answer. Do you know if this limit/ofset is something that is usually done when doing the request to the API , or something you do after you have received the request from the API. Sorry if this sounds a bit strange, I am quite new to databases and APIs

Comment: it depends on the API  - if the API has got the capabilities to recieve this parameters it can be done on the server, if not you would still have to request 2000 items if you offset 1990 with a limit of 10 - you would discard the first 1990 hits on the client site - theres not much sense to do so. Paging is mentioned in your API - Link, but with other limits:  https://musicbrainz.org/doc/Development/XML_Web_Service/Version_2#Paging

Comment: And the last one, sorry for the overtime. These "browse" requests they mention in the website, are ordinary requests, such as the one I would do in Python with: requests.get(URL) ?

Comment: @sdiabr think so, there is also a python2/3 package: http://python-musicbrainzngs.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6/ which might make it easier. See http://python-musicbrainzngs.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6/usage/#regular-musicbrainz-data .. I havent used that so better first read about authetication using that