# How can I paginate this automatically rather than using limit and offset in flask

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I want that each page has 25 rows and there should be a way in which I can access previous and next pages. Below is the code that I wrote. I tried to use limit and offset but then I dont know how to use that in url and that would become unwantedly complex too.

I tried following multiples posts on stackoverflow but couldnt get help.

[Paginate results, offset and limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51142643/paginate-results-offset-and-limit)

I just need to know what needs to be done and I will do it myself

```
def api_split(le):
a="%s,"*le
return a[:-1]

def app_complex_split(st,obj):
    s=""
    if st=="topic":
        for _ in range(len(obj)):
            s+=' bsub.name like %s COLLATE utf8_general_ci or bs.name like %s COLLATE utf8_general_ci or'
        return s[:-3]
    elif st=="author":
        for _ in range(len(obj)):
            s+=' a.name like %s COLLATE utf8_general_ci or'
        return s[:-3]
    elif st=="title":
        for _ in range(len(obj)):
            s+=' b.title like %s COLLATE utf8_general_ci or'
        return s[:-3]


@app.route('/api/v1/books', methods=['GET'])
def api_specific():
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(CONNECTION_DETAILS)
    query_parameters = request.args
    #prev = query_parameters.get('prev')
    #next = query_parameters.get('next')
    book_id = query_parameters.get('book_id')
    lang = query_parameters.get('lang')
    mime_type = query_parameters.get('mime_type')
    topic = query_parameters.get('topic')
    author = query_parameters.get('author')
    title = query_parameters.get('title')

    query = '''SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS b.title "title",a.name "author",b.media_type "genre",GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT l.code) "language",GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT bsub.name) "subject(s)",GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT bs.name) "bookshelf(s)",GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT f.url) "links"
    FROM books_book b
inner join books_book_authors ba on b.id=ba.book_id
inner join books_author a on a.id=ba.author_id
inner join books_book_bookshelves bss on ba.book_id=bss.book_id
inner join books_bookshelf bs on bss.bookshelf_id=bs.id
inner join books_book_subjects bsubs on bsubs.book_id=ba.book_id
inner join books_subject bsub on bsubs.subject_id=bsub.id
inner join books_format f on f.book_id=ba.book_id
inner join books_book_languages ls on ls.book_id=ba.book_id
inner join books_language l on ls.language_id=l.id
where'''
    to_filter = tuple()
    if book_id:
        book_var=tuple(book_id.split(","))
        query += ' b.gutenberg_id in ('+api_split(len(book_var))+') AND'
        to_filter+=book_var
    if lang:
        lang_var=tuple(lang.split(","))
        query += ' l.code in ('+api_split(len(lang_var))+') AND'
        to_filter+=lang_var
    if mime_type:
        if ',' in mime_type:
            mime_type_var=tuple(mime_type.split(","))
        else:
            mime_type_var=tuple(mime_type)
        query += ' f.mime_type in ('+api_split(len(mime_type_var))+') AND'
        to_filter+=mime_type_var
    if topic:
        topic_var=tuple(topic.split(","))
        query += app_complex_split("topic",topic_var)+' AND'
        topic_var=list(topic_var)
        for item in range(len(topic_var)):
            topic_var[item]="%"+topic_var[item]+"%"
        topic_var2=tuple(topic_var)*2
        to_filter+=topic_var2
    if author:
        author_var=tuple(author.split(","))
        query += app_complex_split("author",author_var)+' AND'
        author_var=list(author_var)
        for item in range(len(author_var)):
            author_var[item]="%"+author_var[item]+"%"
        author_var2=tuple(author_var)
        to_filter+=author_var2
    if title:
        title_var=tuple(title.split(","))
        query += app_complex_split("title",title_var)+' AND'
        title_var=list(title_var)
        for item in range(len(title_var)):
            title_var[item]="%"+title_var[item]+"%"
        title_var2=tuple(title_var)
        to_filter+=title_var2

    query = query[:-4]

    query+=''' GROUP by b.title,a.name,b.media_type order by b.download_count desc LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0;'''
    if conn.is_connected():
        cursor = conn.cursor(dictionary=True)
        cursor.execute(query,to_filter)
        record = cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.execute('SELECT FOUND_ROWS() "count";')
        count=cursor.fetchall()
        t={}
        t.update(count[0])
        t["result"]=record
        #t=count+t
    conn.close()
    return jsonify(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's perfect that you know how many rows you want per page, but you're gonna need to buff it out and learn about [forms](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) and the [post requests in flask](https://pythonprogramming.net/flask-get-post-requests-handling-tutorial/). You won't need to make a form, but you need to understand how the page number will be passed back to the server. Assuming the api_specific route the client will access the url at:

```
/api/v1/books?pg=PAGE_NUMBER_GOES_HERE
```

In terms of the SQL, replace SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS with

```
COUNT(book_id) AS book_count
```

because [it's faster](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/). Assuming we gathered all of the books in one query, the book_count value for the first page should be between 0 and 25, the book_count value for the second page should be between 25 and 50, etc. etc. This is where you need the input from the user: to know what page they are on. (It's easier than it looks, you can also just turn the buttons for the pagination into links to the route url along with the page number).

Once you have the page number, you want to multiply the value by 25. This will be the upper book_count value we are searching for. Subtract 25 from the product and you have the lower bound!

Here's a structure you can try.

```
SELECT book_name, col_var, other_vat ,(SELECT max(book_id) FROM TableNameHere WHERE ... AND COUNT(book_id) = (25* (PAGE#-1)) as lower_bound FROM books WHERE LIMIT 25 OFFSET lower_bound;
```

Essentially we find the largest book_id (the last id found by traversing the database until we find 25* (PAGE#-1) values, and start a second query by offsetting at the index and continuing our search for no more than 25 valid rows.